# Windows Batch For-Loop 'input line too long'

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-processing

My FOR-loops recently created some annoying error messages on both my Windows 10 and 11 computers. I could sware they worked before.

The following three command lines work fine and create the expected results:

```
powershell.exe -Command Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName'
pwsh.exe -Command Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName'
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "LocaleName"
```

But if I enclose them into for-loops for a SetVar-like command as follows, all three create the error message, "the entered line is too long". This happens both with **cmd.exe** and **wt.exe**, and both in direct mode and in batch mode (with `%%v`). Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %v in (`powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName'`) do set "LOCALE=%v"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %v in (`pwsh.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKCU:Control Panel\International\' -Name 'LocaleName'`) do set "LOCALE=%v"
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %v in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "LocaleName"') do set "LOCALE=%v"
```

Originally, I thought about a `PowerShell` issue, but then found the same effect with `REG QUERY`.

Comment: If you are using powershell anyway, why not writing the whole script in powershell? Then you won't have any issues with the ancient batch language.

Comment: Of course, the for-loops are part of many batch scripts, and it is never easy to change the language for ~ 100 large scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what happened - after being back from vacation, everything works as before, though nothing changed in the meantime. I will keep an eye on the issue and add here if something changes again, but for now, I close it.